# Function won't select data from database

Tags: php, function, select

I'm working on a new website at the moment and I have a bit of a problem. 
I look if an item exist, if it does, it will execute an insert query. The insert query works but the problem is that the select query doesn't work

Class

```
    public function doubt($event_id)
    {

    $exist = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE id=?");
    $exist->bind_param('s', $event_id);
    $exist->execute();
    $exist->get_result();

    if($exist->num_rows != null) 
    {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $date = $now->getTimestamp();

    $status = 2;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO absence (user_id,event_id,status,ip,date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_SESSION['user_session'], $event_id, $status, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


    return true;            
    }
    else
    {
    return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: `The query works `? which one worked?

Comment: any error in code?

Comment: Sorry, the insert query worked but the select didn't worked

Comment: there is no error, but the if statement returns false and it needs to return true

Comment: the `return false` statement is useless. If you doesn't return, it's false.

Comment: Try to simplify your code. Do a select all and var_dump the results. It works?

Comment: Got it worked, thanx